# syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ':' - RUBY

Tags: ruby

```
prompt("Welcome to Calculator! Enter your name:")

name = ''
loop do
    name = Kernel.gets().chomp()

    if name.empty()? 
        prompt("Make sure to use a valid name")
    else
        break
    end
end
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

I got this error messsage:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ':'
```

Comment: BTW, you can omit all those parentheses, especially the empty ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line

```
if name.empty()?
```

is interpreted as ternary 'if' operator inside regular if statement:

```
if (name.empty() ? do_somethig : do_something_else )
```

and double dot is missing in your code

maybe you meant this:

```
if name.empty? # is equal to
if name.empty?()
```

Because question mark is a part of method name

Answer (score 3):

Try out

```
if name.empty?
```

Note that you can call methods that have no params without parentheses. Otherwise you should do `name.empty?()` because `?` is part of the name of the method.

Anyway, your mistake is the `?` after the `if` condition. The error message is saying you that with that `?` it's trying to process a ternary operator that has this syntax

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

for this reason it expects `:`